# why does python introduced PYTHONCASEOK option?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

As I understood, PYTHONCASEOK option enables importing modules by matching case insensitively. But, as almost everything in python is case sensitive, why does it has to enable this option enabling more lazy writing.

Any other reason for introducing?

Comment: Because not all platforms have case sensitive file systems? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/

Comment: Because some filesystems are case-insensitive perhaps? The option only works on platforms with case-insensitive filesystems.

Comment: ok thanks..I am not aware of this before.

Comment: For example, if you have two modules on your `sys.path`, named `Foo.py` and `foo.py`, *without this option*, `import foo` will find the first and then raise `NameError`, because the filesystem says `foo` and `Foo` are the same but Python sees them as different. The later `foo.py` won't be found. With the `PYTHONCASEOK ` option on, the first `Foo.py` will be imported.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm confused a bit, how Foo.py and foo.py both exists in the first place if the filesystem is case insensitive?

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik: They can exist *on the `sys.path` search path*, which spans multiple directories. If both `ham/spam` and `bar/baz` are part of `sys.path` then `ham/spam/Foo.py` and `bar/baz/foo.py` qualify.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh yes..right!! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of PYTHONCASEOK is to enable finding module files on filesystems which are case-insensitive such as `FAT`, or which behave in a case-insensitive manner from point of view of the programmer, such as `NTFS` on Windows.

It exists to support code written for case-insensitive filesystems before case-sensitivity became the default behaviour when searching for modules in python 2.1.

The detailed explanation for the change is available in [PEP 235](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/)

One interesting scenario described in the PEP is that some operating systems - such as OpenVMS - might change the case of a filename when the file is written:

> if you create "fiLe", there's no telling
>       what it's stored as -- but most likely as "FILE" -- and any of the
>       16 obvious variations on open("FilE") will open it.

so a case-insensitive method of finding the module is a necessity on such as system.

Comment: To add, it is the *filesystem* that is case-insensitive, not the operating system - although Windows greys this distinction.  Strictly speaking the NTFS filesystem (Windows default) is case-sensitive (at an attempt to be POSIX compliment), but Windows itself forces case-insensitivity.  The OSX default filesystem is case insensitive, but it supports case-sensitive as well.  Typically UNIX/Linux filesystems are case sensitive, but DVD's or FAT memory sticks mounted on them are insensitive. Sharing drives between Windows and UNIX is fun.  Confusing, and good reason for PYTHONCASEOK.